# C++ forward decleration of class in namespace with smart pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, forward-declaration

Due to a cyclic dependency with the video class i am forward declaring an class which is inside another namespace. This class is used for a shared pointer which is stored in the mmu class. Once i assign the shared pointer in the constructor of the class, it errors out with `invalid use of incomplete type ‘using element_type = class graphic::Video {aka class graphic::Video}’`
.

mmu.h

```
#pragma once
#include "../cartridge/cartridge.h"

/* forward decleration */
namespace graphic {
    class Video;
}

namespace memory {

    class Mmu {
        public:

            std::shared_ptr<Cartridge> cartridge;
            std::shared_ptr<graphic::Video> video;


            Mmu(std::shared_ptr<Cartridge>&, std::shared_ptr<graphic::Video>&);

    };
}
```

mmu.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mmu.h"

namespace memory {
    Mmu::Mmu(std::shared_ptr<Cartridge> &_cartridge, std::shared_ptr<graphic::Video> &_vid)
    : video(_vid)
    {
        video->initializeColorPallete(); //errors
    }
```

caller.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "caller.h"

Caller::Caller(std::vector<uint8_t> cartridgeData) 
    :cartridge(getCartridge(std::move(cartridgeData))),
     cpu(std::make_unique<cpu::CPU>(mmu)),
     video(std::make_shared<graphic::Video>(mmu, cpu)),
     mmu(std::make_shared<memory::Mmu>(cartridge, video))
    {

    }
```

`video->initializeColorPallete();` errors out in the constructor.

Comment: So quote that error in full.

Comment: Because `graphic::Video` is still an incomplete type at the time of calling the method on it. Include the actual class into your cpp file.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You never included the file in `mmu.cpp` that defines `Video`.

Comment: On top of that, you will need a destructor for class `Mmu` defined in the cpp for the `std::shared_ptr<graphic::Video>` member. The default destructor generated from declaration wouldn't know how to destruct a `graphic::Video` object.

Comment: @ypnos But the `std::shared_ptr` does.  The OP doesn't need to manually define one.

Comment: To say with different words what has been spoken: Forward declarations help to break out of cyclic dependencies in header files, but the full definition is still required to **use** this type. How else could compiler know if `graphic::Video` type has method `initializeColorPallete`, how many parameters it takes and what is it's return type.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I take that back. What I said only applies to unique_ptr. I don't see why it is different to shared_ptr though. 

Comment: @ypnos - _yes_, the underlying object needs to have a destructor, _if_ it explicitly acquires a resource. _no_, if all members of the object have a destructor. There's no distance between unique_ptr and shared_ptr, they both have destructors. THAT said, "always have a destructor" is not bad default behavior. Better than the alternative! I like to explicitly set a default destructor just to signal in my code "I've thought about memory management".

Comment: (ok, I should qualify that. I put a default destructor sometimes _when the [rule of 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) applies_. Adding a default destructor vs implicit destructor has an effect and you shouldn't do it for POD/aggregate types, etc).

Comment: Just simply adding a full definition of `class Video` wouldn't work as well since `class Mmu` is also used in the `class Video`.

Comment: @parktomatomi Thanks, but you're not really answering my question. Try to have a class member `unique_ptr<T>` with forward-declared `T`. At least with current GCC, it will not compile (when the class is instantiated) without having a destructor declared that is defined somewhere where `T` is known (can be empty). With `shared_ptr<T>`, surprisingly for me, the problem does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, I just skimmed the mini-debate about requiring destructors, guilty. For this problem, if you want to use `Video` without knowing its interface, it needs to at minimum be a polymorphic interface with that method and a virtual destructor defined. Then the implementation can override it and you don't have to include it in Cartridge.

Answer (score -1):

So, just reiterating your requirements:

- You don't know the full implementation of `Video`
- You need to *use* `Video` in `Mmu`
- `Video` needs an `Mmu`, directly or indirectly, creating a cyclic type dependency.

This is a good fit for a pure virtual interface. Make a contract with only the methods of `Video` needed by `Mmu`:

```cpp
/* instead of a forward decleration */
namespace graphic {
    class IVideo {
    public:
        virtual void initializeColorPallete() = 0;
        virtual ~IVideo() = default; // always always always needed with interfaces
    };
}
```

Because these are virtual methods, a consumer of an `IVideo` doesn't need to know any details about the full type, because there will be a little table of function pointers at the top called a `vtable`.

Then `Mmu` will take an `IVideo`

```cpp
namespace memory {
    class Mmu {
        public:

            std::shared_ptr<Cartridge> cartridge;
            std::shared_ptr<graphic::IVideo> video;
            Mmu(std::shared_ptr<Cartridge>, std::shared_ptr<graphic::IVideo>);
    };
}
```

And `Video` will *implement* `IVideo`:

```cpp
// Mmu doesn't need to know anything about me
class Video : public graphic::IVideo {
    void initializeColorPallete() override { /* doin' its thing */ }
};
```

And you can pass a smart pointer of `Video` to the `IVideo` input of `Mmu`:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<graphic::IVideo> my_video = std::make_shared<Video>(/*...*/);
```

Because the destructor of `IVideo` is virtual, `shared_ptr` can safely delete it without know anything more about the implementation.

Another small tip: don't use lvalue references to smart pointers. `shared_ptr` depends on the copying of value types to count its dependencies. Same with `unique_ptr` which needs to be moved to be transferred.

*Another* small tip: cycles can be a bit dangerous with shared_ptr. If you pass a `weak_ptr` at some point in the cycle, that will prevent a memory leak. In general, prefer `unique_ptr` for ownership and dumb pointers/references for non-ownership but that's a different debate.